# error al comprobar si el correo fue enviado usando php, libreria phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

```
$mail->Send();

if(!$mail->Send()) 
{ 
  header("location: ../tickets-sin-revisar-1?falloelenvio");
} 
else 
{ 
  header("location: ../tickets-sin-revisar-1?enviado");
}
```

Al usarlo en el correo que envío se envia 2 veces.
si solo uso

```
 $mail->Send();
```

se manda una sola vez, ¿por qué? 
¿qué error tengo en esa comprobación?

Comment: Juan es un error de comprensión más que nada. Cualquier comprobación que hagas en un `if` que conlleve una acción, implica que esa acción se ejecutará. Por tanto puedes dejarlo así: `if(!$mail->Send()) ` o bien guardar el resultado de la ejecución en una variable y usarla en la comprobación: `$mailStatus=$mail->Send(); if(!$mailStatus) { //... }` En tu caso el código podría simplificarse aún más usando un operador ternario.

Comment: podrias explicarme como es eso del operador ternario con un ejemplo? @A.Cedano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es evidente que cualquier comprobación que implique una ejecución significa que esa acción se ejecutará antes de hacer la comprobación.  Por tanto aquí:

```
if(!$mail->Send())
```

Debe ejecutarse primero el método para poder evaluar el resultado de la ejecución del mismo. Por eso el email se enviaba dos veces.

Como solución puedes dejarlo una sola vez, entendiendo que haciéndolo dentro del `if` haces al mismo tiempo el envío del mensaje.

O puedes guardar el resultado en una variable y usar dicha variable para hacer la comprobación.

Otra cosa que se puede mejorar en el código es usar un operador ternario para hacer la redirección.

Por ejemplo:

```
$isSent=$mail->Send();
$url= ( $isSent ) ? "../tickets-sin-revisar-1?enviado" : "../tickets-sin-revisar-1?falloelenvio";
header("Location: $url");
```

Lo que se ha hecho en el código de más arriba ha sido:

1. Guardar el resultado del envío en la variable `$isSent`
2. Usar un ternario para asignar un valor u otro a  `$url` si `$isSent` es `TRUE` o `FALSE`. Es una evaluación parecida a un `if`. Aquí `($isSent)` se pregunta si esa variable es  `TRUE` o `FALSE`. Si es `TRUE`, la variable resultante (`$url`)  adquirirá el valor que está a la izquierda de los dos puntos `:`, de lo contrario adquiere el valor que está a la derecha...
3. Usar el valor que tenga `$url` según la evaluación hecha en el ternario para hacer la redirección.

**Nótese** que en mi caso preferí hacer las evaluaciones en positivo (evitando el uso de `!`), lo prefiero así, porque me parece que hay más claridad en lo que se evalúa.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!$mail->Send()) 
{ 
  header("location: ../tickets-sin-revisar-1?falloelenvio");
} 
else 
{ 
  header("location: ../tickets-sin-revisar-1?enviado");
}
```

el problema ya lo vi, es que en la comprobacion estaba la accion de enviar el correo .
en el , bueno espero que a otros le sirva 
" if(!$mail->Send()) "